# Signing Client Certificates from Firefox for Authentication

Tags: firefox, ssl, openssl, authentication

My organization is looking to move to using client certificates for authentication on our internal websites. It's a medium-sized business that uses Firefox across the entire organization.

I initially looked at using Firefox's `window.crypto.generateCRMFRequest()` and `window.crypto.importUserCertificates()` javascript functions for certificate request generation and enrollment, but their use is seemingly completely undocumented.

For `window.crypto.importUserCertificates()` to work, [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto/importUserCertificates) claims that any certificates must have a corresponding request ID (presumingly generated with generateCRMFRequest()) to be imported successfully. I was able to successfully generate a CRMF request with `window.crypto.generateCRMFRequest()`, but could not figure out how to generate a CMMF Certification Response.

OpenSSL seems to have no support for CRMF requests, but it can read the ASN.1 request:

```
$ cat example.crmf
 MIIBiDCCAYQwgesCBF7ts6IwgcmAAQKlEDAOMQwwCgYDVQQDEwN2dnamgZ8wDQYJ
 KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAME59JllBjW38By5ECaTatTd1hHY3Mrmzd+Z
 pm3XrLbS8u0A4kkFozm/Yrrwzzl4w/mdJwNxuOv+5CMr3u9VFDHj5SPOgSBUlR/v
 f9x9kqPVUeD21Rkv6YkS0flg8LpU22PMZgw1PtnbVXDGrkUvXr0ygF2En5ZvaL47
 hhZEZn3DAgMBAAGpEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBeAwFzAVBgkrBgEFBQcFAQEMCHJl
 Z1Rva2VuoYGTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAHx/KinpGg0+kjmF9ThduXDMuv9c
 d2qE4xiCqsrEbLScCtrk+4RNnthRnQ7UXGSSwTYh/gJs0LAr4EFSvWJEnNeKNY2V
 RqUD1LERr1pnTcGzZR5SCbQ6ASKqi99BgvoidAyYtAhrgLbttLIdsgHBldV8vOlL
 MUi5Ya1etnfZHsTt 

$ base64 -d example.crmf > example.der
$ openssl asn1parse -in example.der -inform der
 0:d=0  hl=4 l= 392 cons: SEQUENCE          
 4:d=1  hl=4 l= 388 cons: SEQUENCE          
 8:d=2  hl=3 l= 235 cons: SEQUENCE          
 11:d=3  hl=2 l=   4 prim: INTEGER           :5EEDB3A2
 17:d=3  hl=3 l= 201 cons: SEQUENCE          
 20:d=4  hl=2 l=   1 prim: cont [ 0 ]        
 23:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 cons: cont [ 5 ]        
 25:d=5  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE          
 27:d=6  hl=2 l=  12 cons: SET               
 29:d=7  hl=2 l=  10 cons: SEQUENCE          
 31:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
 36:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :vvv
 41:d=4  hl=3 l= 159 cons: cont [ 6 ]        
 44:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
 46:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
 57:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
 59:d=5  hl=3 l= 141 prim: BIT STRING        
 203:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 cons: cont [ 9 ]        
 205:d=5  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE          
 207:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Usage
 212:d=6  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BOOLEAN           :255
 215:d=6  hl=2 l=   4 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:030205E0
 221:d=3  hl=2 l=  23 cons: SEQUENCE          
 223:d=4  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE          
 225:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :id-regCtrl-regToken
 236:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: UTF8STRING        :regToken
 246:d=2  hl=3 l= 147 cons: cont [ 1 ]        
 249:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
 251:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
 262:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
 264:d=3  hl=3 l= 129 prim: BIT STRING
```

It's frustrating, because startssl's site has no problem with them.

**So, my question is:** What magic must happen on the server side to process CRMF requests and issue certificates that can be imported with `window.cypto.importUserCertificates()`?

*Note: This question is purely for curiosity sake now, I've since solved my authentication issues by generating each certificate myself with OpenSSL. The security-conscious engineer in me isn't a big fan of the way I completed my tasking (specifically, I generated everyone's private keys), but there wasn't enough time to tinker with this. :(*

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Java on the server side, here is a Gist that shows how to read the content of a CRMF request using BouncyCastle: https://gist.github.com/503932

You should then treat it more or less like a CSR from the CA's point of view (i.e. get the public key material, bind it to an identity you have verify out of bands and sign the bundle as a certificate.)

There are examples in this [MiniCaCertGen](https://github.com/harbulot/webidrepository/blob/master/core/src/main/java/uk/ac/manchester/rcs/bruno/keygenapp/base/MiniCaCertGen.java) class to issue certificates. It takes the code from this [script](https://github.com/harbulot/webidrepository/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/uk/ac/manchester/rcs/bruno/webidrepository/htdocs/crosskeygen.js), which can work (for IE on both XP and Vista/7, which have different APIs), as well as using `<keygen/>`. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt that code to handle the CRMF requests too. In addition, as far as I remember, Firefox still supports the old `<keygen/>` anyway (and it came back on the scene for HTML 5).

You may also be interested in existing solutions, such as [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/projects/openca/).